# Include js files outside static directory in node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i'm building a platform which has a folder called "extensions" in which are stored some plugins activable for the user (the activation is based upon a db table that records the userid and the plugin he bought).
For each extension, the file structure has a folder called "js" in which i store the jquery valid for the views of the extensions.
My problem is : how can i include the js script of those extensions even if they are not in the express static directory?

Comment: Where is the folder `extensions` located?

Comment: It is located in the root of the project, as a sibling of the "public" static directory